# sql server and statistics profile

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, statistics, query-optimization

I am starting to look at the query optimizer in SQL server 2008 and I’m particularly interested in the statistics profile that can be shown for a query. So far i understand that the result shown for the statistics profile is based on the statistics stored in SQL server and not the results from executing the query (e.g., the ‘`Rows`’ column), right?

Now, is there a way to get the result from the statistics profile without executing the actual query at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SET STATISTICS_PROFILE ON` returns both actual and estimated row counts.

If you want just estimated row counts without running the query use `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` or `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON`

Comment: Hi, when i use the showplan_all i won’t get the column 'Rows' - so do this mean this column is only available together with the actual execution of the query?

Comment: Yes. It gives you the column `EstimateRows`. Actual is only available when executing the query.

Comment: Okay, i can say that in my example i get a actual row count on 326 and estimated on 9,66 which seems like a quite bad estimation :)

Comment: That might not be too bad it isn't orders of magnitude out but make sure you are using sargable expressions so the query optimiser gets the best possible chance of using its statistics.

Comment: Okay thanks - just a final question, is it possible to get the statistics by executing a ‘normal’ query from my application, such that I won’t need to use the management studio to get the result?

Comment: @aweis - Not something I've ever tried. Presumably it will just come back as a second result set that your application can consume though?